# React query optimistic update refetches data

Tags: react-native

I am using React query's `useInfiniteQuery` to manage api calls in my react native component. I would like to implement like feature on the data from react query. This has to be done optimistically. I have created the following custom hook to help with that

```js
export function useUnlikePost() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const {mutate: unlikePostHandler} = useMutation(
    async (post: IFeedPost) => {
      let optimisticPost = {...post};

      if (optimisticPost.likeReactionId) {
        const id = optimisticPost.likeReactionId;
        optimisticPost.likeReactionId = undefined;
        optimisticPost.totalLikes -= 1;

        // Unlike the post on the server
        await unlikePost(id, optimisticPost, optimisticPost.id);

        return optimisticPost;
      }

      return post;
    },
    {
      // When mutate is called
      onMutate: async (post: IFeedPost) => {
        // Cancel any outgoing refetches
        await queryClient.cancelQueries(['likedPosts']);

        // Snapshot the previous value
        const previousLikesData = queryClient.getQueryData('likedPosts');

        // Optimistically update to the new value
        queryClient.setQueryData('likedPosts', (old: any) =>
          old?.pages.map((page: IFeedPost[]) =>
            page.map(p =>
              p.id === post.id
                ? {
                    ...p,
                    likeReactionId: undefined,
                    totalLikes: p.totalLikes - 1,
                  }
                : p,
            ),
          ),
        );

       // rest of the code

  return unlikePostHandler;
}
```

This here is my useInfiniteQuery call

```js
const {
    data,
    error,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isLoading,
    refetch,
    isRefetching,
  } = useInfiniteQuery<IFeedPost[]>({
    queryKey: 'likedPosts',
    queryFn: fetchLikesFeed,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    refetchOnReconnect: false,
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
      if (lastPage?.length === 25) {
        const posts = pages.flat();
        return posts.length - 1;
      }
      return undefined;
    },
  });
```

And this is how I am using the hook

````
          onLikePress={() => unLikePost(post)}
          totalLikes={post.totalLikes}
          liked={post.likeReactionId}
        />```

Would anyone be so kind as to tell me why the component reloads/refetches data upon unliking a post?
````